# Oblique asymptotes

Tags: calculus

When we find oblique asymptotes, we divide the numerator by the denominator and take only the polynomial portion of the expression as the equation of the slant asymptote. Why? What is the proof that this equation is the slant asymptote?

Comment: If you've properly split the rational function you have into a "polynomial part" and a "proper rational function part"; that is, $$p(x)+\frac{r(x)}{s(x)}$$, where the degree of $r(x)$ is less than the degree of $s(x)$, see what happens as $x$ increases without bound.

Comment: Thanks. A hint in the right direction was what I needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're interested in the behaviour of the function as $|x|$ grows large. You can split the function up. I'll take an example:

$$\frac{3x^2+1}{x+2}$$
$$\frac{3x(x+2)-6x+1}{x+2}$$
$$3x+\frac{-6x+1}{x+2}$$
$$3x+\frac{-6(x+2)+13}{x+2}$$
$$3x-6+\frac{13}{x+2}$$

at each step I'm rewriting the highest term in a way that involves $x+2$, and then adjusting the lower terms so that the expansion comes out right. Now look what happens to the fraction as $x$ grows large:

$$\frac{13}{102},\frac{13}{1002},\frac{13}{10002}, \cdots$$

It gets smaller and smaller and goes to $0$. You can show the same thing for the other direction as well (negative numbers that get closer and closer to zero). So an asymptote is concerned with behaviour *as $x$ grows large*, and as $x$ grows large the fractional portion drops out to $0$. It only influences the function near the origin, which the asymptote isn't concerned with.

Comment: should it not be 11/(x+2) not 13/(x+2)? Just wondering, but i may be wrong because i'm also just new at this...

Comment: @user82460 The -6(x+2) will introduce a -12. To make everything equal to the +1 in the numerator I need to add 13 back.

Answer (score 0):

Comment

[image]

A hypebola is obtained by multiplication of a pair of straight lines with an added constant.

Please note how the vertical deviations from product hyperbola (blue, red) from its oblique asymptotes tend to zero when approaching to $\pm \infty $ on either side... i.e., how the effect of added constant should D vanish.